# How do I make/extract/modify source of a package and repack it?

Tags: packaging

I have a package which has bug, and i need to modify it, and repack it, So thats how i am doing. Is there any other quick methods?

1. List/View only (drivers files or applications)

   ```
   ar tv DesktopVideo-8.0.1-amd64.deb
   rw-r--r-- 0/0      4 Sep 25 07:35 2011 debian-binary
   rw-r--r-- 0/0 14942208 Sep 25 07:35 2011 control.tar.gz
   rw-r--r-- 0/0    102 Sep 25 07:35 2011 data.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract

   ```
   ar x DesktopVideo-8.0.1-amd64.deb
   control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz debian-binary
   ```
3. Extract tar.gz

   ```
   tar xvfz control.tar.gz
   tar xvfz data.tar.gz
   ;; modify my codes and updates
   ```
4. Repack/Rebuild this back

   ```
   mkdir -p debian/DEBIAN
   ; step 1
   cp -R ./debian-binary debina/DEBIAN
   cp -R ./control debian/DEBIAN
   cp -R ./control debian/DEBIAN
   cp -R ./control debian/DEBIAN
   ; step 2
   cp -R ./etc debian/DEBIAN
   cp -R ./usr debian/DEBIAN
   ```
5. Make .DEB now

   ```
   ; this is how the skeleton look like before applying --build
   root@desktop:~/Downloads/test# ls
   control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian  debian-binary  etc  usr

   root@desktop:~/Downloads/test# dpkg-deb --build debian
   dpkg-deb: building package `desktopvideo' in `debian.deb'.
   ```

-- Failed

```
# dpkg -i DesktopVideo-8.0.1-amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing DesktopVideo-8.0.1-amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//etc': Is a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 DesktopVideo-8.0.1-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already, install the build tools: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

You can use the `apt-get source DesktopVideo` command to pull the source, diffs, and all other packaging files associated with that deb into the current directory. From there apply your patch, add a new entry in the log file `dch -i`, then use fakeroot and dpkg to create the package `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc`

Answer (score 2):

It's technically possible to do what you're trying to do, but you need to be far more careful than you seem to be. It's difficult to know what you did wrong because you didn't copy-paste everything you typed. I do spot a typo (`cp -R ./debian-binary debina/DEBIAN`, you're obviously not reporting exactly what did ), and a mistake (`cp -R` doesn't preserve ownership and permissions, you would need `cp -Rp` or `cp -a` as root).

The best way to modify a package is to get the package source (`apt-get source DesktopVideo`). Modify the source, then add an entry to the package changelog, changing the version number so that your version is different from the official version number. [Here's an example of the steps involved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/upgrade-xdebug-without-using-apt/3616#3616) (Debian and Ubuntu work identically in this respect).

If you don't have the source or don't want to recompile, you could install the package, then use [`dpkg-divert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html) to move the buggy file(s) out of the way and replace it by your own version. `dpkg-divert` tells the package manager to put a file from a given package in a different location. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/selectively-disabling-gvfsd-cdda-in-debian-squeeze/9732#9732)'s an example of its use.

If you don't have the source of the package and you need to deploy a fix to several machines, you can install the package, then modify the buggy file, and build a new package with [`dpkg-repack`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg-repack.1.html). It's more of an act of desesperation than a robust way to manage packages; I recommend patching the source and deploying your home-compiled package if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve the package source (you only got the binary there) with `apt-get -d source packagename`. Then you can tinker around in it and use `debuild` to build it again.