# How to modify the details of a debian package

Tags: package-management, software-installation, packaging, debian

I am new to Ubuntu and would like to know if there's a way to modify or edit the details of a deb package. For example, I'm running the command:
`sudo dpkg -I myPackage_amd64.deb` and get several categories, such as Version, architecture, section, etc..

How can I remove or change the values of one or more of these categories?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The first obvious question is "Why?" You called this "myPackage_amd64.deb", is this a package you made yourself? Or, is this a .deb that you downloaded from elsewhere and you're trying to make it satisfy a dependency of another .deb?

Comment: It's a simple learning package I downloaded elsewhere and I would like to try changing its properties (add/remove). Is it doable?

Comment: dupe of [How to download, modify, build and install a Debian source package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package) and [How do I make/extract/modify source of a package and repack it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62919/how-do-i-make-extract-modify-source-of-a-package-and-repack-it)

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to do this would be from a source tree. You would get a source tree by either downloading it or executing a command such as `apt-get source some-package`.

Once the source tree is downloaded, you would follow these steps:

1. `cd some-package*/debian`
2. `nano control`
3. The control file holds information for the source tree and packages generated from the source. For the source tree, there are several fields including "Build-Depends", "Maintainer", "Section". For the package, there are fields such as "Architecture", "Depends", "Suggests", and "Description".
4. `nano changelog`
5. This is the version file that contains the changelog for this package. Simply modify the version number, or add your own section above it with your own version number.
6. `debuild -us -uc` will re-build the package with the updated information

However, it's theoretically possible to do this by simply extracting the Debian package. (Note, I did not test this).

1. `ar x SomePackage.deb`
2. `tar -xzf control.tar.gz`
3. `nano control` and edit the information
4. `tar -czf control.tar.gz conffiles control md5sums postinst postrm preinst prerm`
5. `ar r SomePackage.deb control.tar.gz`
6. `rm control.tar.gz data.tar.gz debian-binary conffiles control md5sums postinst postrm preinst prerm`

Comment: Thanks Githlar!!! I have tried your second option and it worked "like magic". I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user279465, would you accept this answer as it is the one that works for you.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138190/38647 suggests a way of unpacking/repacking the .deb file using dpkg-deb, and advises doing everything in a `fakeroot` to preserve permissions.